# Delete a List Item if the Value is found in a column of an Excel

Tags: excel, list, vba

Here's what I want to do.
I have the following piece of code:

```
Private Sub imperecheaza_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rand As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BD_AR")

Rand = 3
Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
    If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = gksluri.Value And ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value = gksluri.List(gksluri.ListIndex, 1) Then
            gksluri.RemoveItem gksluri.ListIndex
    End If
Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

The problem is that it doesn't work and I don't know why. There must be something with the If.
What I want to do is... if the Value of the Listbox is found in the column of the Excel to delete that item.
Also...  it checks for the Value in the 2nd column of the listbox. (the listbox has 8 columns).

To give you an example.

I have the following data in Excel:
[image]

And in the listbox the following items

[image]
When I click on imperecheaza I want the item in the listbox to be removed and the row in the Excel file to be deleted.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Does it throw an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Also, what kind of object is gksluri? It's not defined in your code sample.

Comment: Why dont use thisworkbook.ws.cells instead!

Comment: and also no decleartion of ws2 sheet object and did not use it though

Comment: Hi, by "it doesn't work" I mean that it doesn't remove the item from the list. The items are in the excel and in the list too...The If statement checks for the value from the list in Excel and if it's found (and it should be found) I want to remove the item from the list. The problem is that I don't know what's the problem with the If statement because it doesn't remove the item from the list.

Comment: gksluri is a Listbox... that listbox that you see in the 2nd picture.

Comment: Actually, you should use `Option Explicit` and declare all your vars!

Comment: What values are not declared?

Comment: the listbox (gksluri) is added to the form with drag and drop...

Comment: the strage thing is that if I add a Label there and I make a little peace of code to add all the values in the Excel in that label's caption... it works. If I want to add the value of the listbox in that Label's caption... it works... but if I compare them it doesn't work... I really don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying your listbox values by 1:

```
If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = gksluri.Value * 1 And ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value = gksluri.List(gksluri.ListIndex, 1) * 1 Then
```

Also, you show no code to delete the row!

Comment: Thanks... it works... the problem is that it deletes all of the items :))

Comment: That's probably because after I remove the gksluri.ListIndex ...then the 2nd item in the list becomes selected and I will apply the code for it too and it will delete it... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Exit the loop after you find the match and delete the item and row.  In general, there are more precise and efficient ways to do what you want.  Try to just find the one row that matches your criteria, delete it and then delete the listbox item.